# gradle fatjar include classes from nested Jar

Tags: java, build.gradle

My problem might be simple to gradle experts.

I am building fatJar. One of the dependencies contain Jar file itself. With following piece of code fat jar is being created with all other dependencies but the one that has jar, it just places jars in final jar. Which makes sense. How can I copy all the classes from those nested jars into final Jar. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
jar {
    from {configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }} {

        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes are already inside those jars. There's no need to copy them separately.

Comment: I need to because it doesn't work with API gateway I am working on i.e it fails to locate classes.